# TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.ischecked1')

Tags: react-native, expo

I see the above error, every time I try clicking on my checkboxes
I want individual checks onto the four checkboxes shown below, but I am not able to do it. Please help!
The code is as follows:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { Header, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createNavigatorContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';


export default class UpdateTypes extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'UPDATE TYPES',
    style: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: '#FFD700',
    },
  };

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);     

        this.state = {
            ischecked1: true,
            ischecked2: false,
            ischecked3: true,
            ischecked4: false,
        } 
    }  


  onChangeCheck1() {
    this.setState({ ischecked1: !this.state.ischecked1 });
  }
  onChangeCheck2() {
    this.setState({ ischecked2: !this.state.ischecked2 });
  }
  onChangeCheck3() {
    this.setState({ ischecked3: !this.state.ischecked3 });
  }
  onChangeCheck4() {
    this.setState({ ischecked4: !this.state.ischecked4 });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.innerview}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.options}>
            <Text>Select All</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.options}>
            <Text>Deselect All</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.writeup}>
          Some random Texts. Below are some checkboxes. Bla Bla Bla!
        </Text>

        <View style={StyleSheet.create({ flex: 1 })}>
          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxA"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            value={this.state.ischecked1}
            checked={this.state.ischecked1}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck1}
          />

          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxB"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            checked={this.state.ischecked2}
            value={this.state.ischecked2}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck2}
          />

          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxC"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            checked={this.state.ischecked3}
            value={this.state.ischecked3}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck3}
          />

          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxD"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            value={this.state.ischecked4}
            checked={this.state.ischecked4}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck4}

          />
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.adsense}>
          <Text>Adsense Ad</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  options: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#008080',
  },
  writeup: {
    flex: 0.3,
    backgroundColor: '#FFE4B5',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 8,
  },
  innerview: {
    flex: 0.4,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  adsense: {
    flex: 0.55,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#778899',
  },
});
```

Also, I am confused, when to use:

- `onChange`
- `onChangeCheck`
- `onIconPress`
- `onLongPress`
- `onPress`

Are these the same, or there are specific usages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is obviously wrong: replace `const state =` with `this.state=`

Also, bind the functions:

```
onPress={this.onChangeCheck1.bind(this)}
```

Updated code (you can add 'deselectAll' in a similar way to 'selectAll'):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';


export default class UpdateTypes extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'UPDATE TYPES',
    style: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: '#FFD700'
    }
  };

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            ischecked1: true,
            ischecked2: false,
            ischecked3: true,
            ischecked4: false
        };
    }


  onChangeCheck1() {
    this.setState({ ischecked1: !this.state.ischecked1 });
  }
  onChangeCheck2() {
    this.setState({ ischecked2: !this.state.ischecked2 });
  }
  onChangeCheck3() {
    this.setState({ ischecked3: !this.state.ischecked3 });
  }
  onChangeCheck4() {
    this.setState({ ischecked4: !this.state.ischecked4 });
  }

  selectAll() {
    this.setState({
      ischecked1: true,
      ischecked2: true,
      ischecked3: true,
      ischecked4: true
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.innerview}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.options} onPress={this.selectAll.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Select All</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.options}>
            <Text>Deselect All</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.writeup}>
          Some random Texts. Below are some checkboxes. Bla Bla Bla!
        </Text>

        <View style={StyleSheet.create({ flex: 1 })}>
          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxA"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            value={this.state.ischecked1}
            checked={this.state.ischecked1}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck1.bind(this)}
          />

          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxB"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            checked={this.state.ischecked2}
            value={this.state.ischecked2}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck2.bind(this)}
          />

          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxC"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            checked={this.state.ischecked3}
            value={this.state.ischecked3}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck3.bind(this)}
          />

          <CheckBox
            center
            title="CheckBoxD"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            value={this.state.ischecked4}
            checked={this.state.ischecked4}
            onPress={this.onChangeCheck4.bind(this)}

          />
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.adsense}>
          <Text>Adsense Ad</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  options: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#008080'
  },
  writeup: {
    flex: 0.3,
    backgroundColor: '#FFE4B5',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 8
  },
  innerview: {
    flex: 0.4,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  adsense: {
    flex: 0.55,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#778899'
  }
});
```

Comment: I have edited the question. You can see the entire code here. Please suggest me any possible solutions. Also, There are two buttons called select all and deselect all, I want them to be functioning too. Can you please see what's wrong?

Comment: Do you still get the same error when you click on a checkbox?

Comment: Yes. If you try copying the code on expo and run it, you'll be able to see the same error

Comment: Pls check the reply

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped. About the later part of question, I think all work the same way right. The onpress, onchange, onchangecheck, onlongpress,?

Comment: Most welcome :) I am not familiar with the component's functions. Give it a try... I assume that the 'long' functions are for... long press, but they don't seem to work for me... They say that onPress is for the CheckBox's container and onPressIcon for the CheckBox. When I use both, onPress doesn't do anything. Just use what is working for you... Or look in their source code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use autobinding or arrow function for onClick event of the checkbox.

```
    onChangeCheck1 = () => {
    this.setState({ ischecked1: !this.state.ischecked1 });
    }
```

It is not getting the 'this' object because the context in which onClick is called is different.